# Angular JS Typescript Unit Testing Karma

Tags: angularjs, typescript, karma-runner

Im currently involved in a project that has used typescript to build its single page anuglar app.  Unfortunately they have done no unit testing.  Being new to using typescript i am having problems getting any testing going.  An example test is below. followed by the typescript file

When i run the test it fails to find the controller !

```
(function() {
'use strict';

    describe('CarController', function() {

        // Load the controllers module
        beforeEach(module('CarDealerApp'));

        var scope,
            CarController ;

        beforeEach(inject(function($controller) {
            scope = {};

            CarController = $controller('CarController', {
                $scope: scope
            });
        }));

        it('should set the car name', function() {

            expect(scope.carMake).toEqual('Ford');

        });

    });

})();


module CarDealerApp.Cars.Controllers {
    "use strict";

    export interface ICarScope extends angular.Scope {
        carName : string;
    }

    export class CarController {

        carName:string = "Ford";

        // $inject annotation
        public static $inject = [
            '$scope'
        ]

        constructor(private $scope: ICarScope){

            $scope.vm = this;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: wouldn't you want to expect scope.vm.carMake or can you just do CarController.carMake?

Answer (score 4):

Although what you have written there works, I suggest constructing your TypeScript controller (in your test) like so:

```
CarController = new CarDealerApp.Cars.Controllers.CarController($rootScope.$new());
```

Which is a cleaner construction, and is the proper way to do it when you're writing your TypeScript tests.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got this working.

Basically I needed to pass in the full module name for the controller like this:

`CarController = $controller('CarDealerApp.Cars.Controllers.CarController');`